# Java - How can I edit the size and position of a button using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, size, jbutton, layout-manager

I have the following code but I'd like to structure several buttons of certain sizes. I'm just wondering how to do this as I've Googled it and found several different methods but none seem to work. Any advice?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(500, 500);
        window.setTitle("My Application");

        JButton button = new JButton("click me");
        window.add(button);

        window.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to give more detail for your question to be answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are taking your first steps into swing. The questions that you are asking belong to an area of gui design called layout. Exactly how you set the position of your button depends hea ily on the layout. I would suggest that you find a swing tutorial and run through it. I started with the Java Swing Trail: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing

In the Java api documents look for BorderLayout and GridLayout. They are the easiest to start with.

Answer (score 2):

From your question I think you are trying to make the button fit the size of the window. In which case you would use `window.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);`

If you are trying to have multiple buttons you need to use a layout. A tutorial for making GUIs in swing using layouts can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Answer (score 2):

In general you can use `setLocation` and `setSize` methods. However, it is best if you use a layout manager. Check [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) tutorial. In your case by default `BorderLayout` is used. If you want an absolute layout you can set it:

```
window.setLayout(null);
```

Then you must specify the size and position of every component within that container.

*EDIT:*

Please note that using [absolute layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) can be complex and usually can be avoided. See [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for some ideas.

Comment: You shouldn't even suggest `null` layouts to people just starting to learn Swing (actually, to nobody in general). Just learn using the available layouts

Answer (score 1):

You really can change the size of your JButton in number of different ways, but it is not a good practice at all to do that in swing, and explicitly give size values to different components. You must better start learning about [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). And it will be much wiser, if you will also learn about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

The default Layout for the JFrame is BorderLayout, as the default for JPanel is FlowLayout.
But as for your question, the simplest way I can think of is as follows :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    /*
                     * THe default Layout for the JFrame is the BorderLayout.
                     * Since you said you have some buttons, so I am giving
                     * you some idea how various buttons can be added to the 
                     * JFrame, with different values.
                     */
                    JFrame window = new JFrame();
                    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    window.setTitle("My Application");

                    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
                    window.add(button1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);                   

                    JButton button2 = new JButton("Button2");
                    window.add(button2, BorderLayout.WEST);

                    JButton button3 = new JButton("Button3");
                    window.add(button3, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                    JButton button4 = new JButton("Button4");
                    window.add(button4, BorderLayout.EAST);

                    JButton button5 = new JButton("Button5");
                    window.add(button5, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

                    window.pack();
                    window.setVisible(true);
                }
            });

    }

}
```

Hope this might help you in some way.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

A [`JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) extends an [`AbstractButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html) which in turn extends a [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html), so, as is the case of inheritance, you can use all the methods provided by `JComponent`.

Related methods you should consider are:

```
setMaximumSize(Dimension maximumSize) Sets the maximum size of this component to a constant value.
setMinimumSize(Dimension minimumSize) Sets the minimum size of this component to a constant value.
```

Moreover, `JComponent` extends [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) which provides, and you can use,

```
setSize(Dimension d) Resizes this component so that it has width d.width and height d.height.
setSize(int width, int height) Resizes this component so that it has width width and height height.
```

see the inheritance below:

```
java.awt.Component
    java.awt.Container
        javax.swing.JComponent
            javax.swing.AbstractButton
                javax.swing.JButton
```

Comment: -1 a) never-ever use any of the setXXSize (XX = min/pref/max) b) never-ever do manual sizing/positioning